# How to add more things to the Power User (Win-X) menu?

Tags: windows-8, context-menu

How can I add more things to the menu that appears when I press the Windows key and X at the same time?

Searching through the web I found [this website](http://www.withinwindows.com/2012/04/04/windows-8-secrets-the-winx-menu-and-its-hashing-algorithm/), but what's there doesn't work.

Perhaps this ability was removed form the release version of Windows 8?

Answer (score 5):

It works, that post you refer to is the old one. Rafael released a new version that is compatible with the Release Preview and still works in the RTM version as well.

You can find an updated post [here](http://www.withinwindows.com/2012/06/01/windows-8-secrets-the-winx-menu-and-its-hashing-algorithm-revisited/) and download the executable program [here](https://github.com/riverar/hashlnk/downloads). The program requires you install the redistributable package of Visual C++ 2010. If you don't want to install it, I just [built](http://goo.gl/sHq2r) it not to depend on it.

It's actually quite useful to me, I use it to have a fast way to restart and shutdown the system:

[image: Custom Win+X menu example]

And the procedure is quite simple actually:

1. Create a shortcut of what you want to have in that menu.
2. Rename it, set up its arguments, etc. Essentially finish it to your liking.
3. Drag and drop that shortcut over the program, or open a command prompt and run:

   `hashlnk path_to_shortcut.lnk`
4. Open a explorer window and navigate to `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\WinX`, or input that in the run dialog (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).
5. There you'll see group folders with shortcuts inside (and you can create more groups), move your shortcut to the group you want it to appear.
6. Restart the Explorer process from the task manager for example, or reboot.

After that the shortcuts will appear in the menu just like any other item there.

**[Here](http://www.askvg.com/exclusive-customize-new-quick-access-menu-win-x-menu-in-windows-8-add-remove-rename-or-move-shortcuts-and-much-more/) you have extensive information on how to customize it too.**

Comment: Thank you it works now, but how did you add Restart ans Shutdown? What program are you using?

Comment: I just have a shortcut to `shutdown -r -t 0` for restart and `shutdown -s -t 0` for shutdown. Their execution opens two `cmd` windows but it's ok by me.

Comment: I just replace it, wrote a small shutdown program so that no command prompt window appears. To use it: if no parameters are specified log-off is performed, `-r` restarts the system and `-s` shuts it down. If you want to force any of those add `-f` too. So I'm using `shutdown2 -r` for restart and `shutdown2 -s` for shutdown. You can grab the executable files and source here: http://goo.gl/3Pdvq

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps check out [Win-X Menu Editor](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.30) by "WinAero".

Found the link via [GHacks.net](http://www.ghacks.net/2012/08/12/edit-the-win-x-menu-in-windows-8/)

Works fine for me (Win 8 Pro x86).  It's got all the needed bits and pieces included with it.

I have no affiliation with any of them. :)

Comment: I have tried it but it didn't allow me to customize the shortcuts once they were added and it crashed once, so I'm going to do the other way. This program is graphical though.

Answer (score 0):

[Download](http://winaero.com/download.php?view.21)  <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> menu editor which will let you achieve what you want.  With <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> Menu Editor you'll able:

> - to add new items.
> - to remove any item of Win+X menu.
> - to change display name of any item of Win+X menu.
> - to reorder Win+X menu items.