# Replace Command Prompt with Powershell on Power User Menu

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, context-menu

I would like to replace the Command Prompt option on the power user (<kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>) menu with and option for Powershell. Like many Windows user I've slowly been transitioning from using the traditional windows command prompt to the more versatile Powershell.

With the introduction of the power user menu in Windows 8, one of the reason I've been slow to change is the convenience of accessing the Command Prompt from the power user menu: three keys, one hand (<kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>).

I'm looking for a way to

1. Add Powershell to the menu (preferably with an equivalent keyboard shortcut)
2. Remove Command Prompt form the menu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the Taskbar and select `Properties` from the menu.

Click on the `Navigation` tab:

[image]

The third checkbox is want to want.

This works in Windows 8.1, not sure about Windows 8.0.

And if you like PowerShell, you can use:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" -Name DontUsePowerShellOnWinX -PropertyType DWord –Value 0 -force
```

but changing the registry doesn't change the menu immediately, you have to log off and on again.

Comment: Looks like I should learn to KISS

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to do this aside from what is mentioned in questions such as [How to add more things to the Power User (Win-X) menu?](https://superuser.com/q/499038/457117) that specifically replaces the Command Prompt with Powershell.

To accomplish this, all  that needs to be done is merging this `reg` file with the main registry.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"DontUsePowerShellOnWinX"=dword:00000000
```

or navigating to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced` inside Regedit and setting the key `DontUsePowerShellOnWinX` to `0`.